# How to unit test a method for timeout exception in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I want to test a method which makes a call to a service, if the call to that service times out I am displaying a negative feedback to user. How to unittest the timeout use case ??

My method looks like:

```
def method
  x = callservice()
  if x[:value]
    display_positve_feedback("positive")
  else
    display_negative_feedback("negative")
  end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    display_negative_feedback("Timeout, please wait for 5 mins and check again")
  end
end
```

I have mocked callservice but how to I make that service Timeout to check the timeout use case???

Comment: Your method has a syntax error (a missing begin after `def method`?).

Comment: @knut Adding `begin` to the top of the method would fix the syntax error, but removing the extra `end` instead would be preferable (`def method; rescue; end` is preferable to `def method; begin; rescue; end; end`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a return code. If you add it, you could test for the method result.

Example:

```
def method
  begin
    x = callservice()
    if x[:value]
      display_positve_feedback("positive")
      return true
    else
      display_negative_feedback("negative")
      return false
    end
    rescue Timeout::Error => e
      display_negative_feedback("Timeout, please wait for 5 mins and check again")
      return nil
  end
  raise "This should never happen"
end
```

Now you can test on `true`, `false`or `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing exceptions is usually not a good practice that I would recommend to anyone.

When you catch (rescue) the timeout exception, re-raise it (or your own application-specific one) in the rescue code and have the caller (your test) check that an exception is thrown for the timeout.

You could use `assert_raise` or expect `raise_error`, for example, depending on what testing framework you use.

Using an exception, the calling code only needs to know about a potential exception rather than having to check for specific return values, which makes the code simpler and more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Stub the `callservice` method to raise a `Timeout::Error`. How you'll do that depends on what testing framework you're using. For example, in RSpec it might look something like this:

```
my_obj.stub(:callservice) { raise Timeout::Error }

expect(my_obj).to receive(:display_negative_feedback)
  .with("Timeout, please wait for 5 mins and check again")

my_obj.method
```